# Can I play Pokemon Go with a slow (384kbps) cell phone data plan?

Tags: pokemon-go

To save money, I’m thinking of switching to a cheap data plan with unlimited data, but which has the data transmission speed capped at 384 kbps.

I’m wondering if this data transmission speed is sufficient for playing Pokemon Go?

Answer (score 2):

I found this page earlier: http://techwelkin.com/meaning-mobile-symbols-g-e-2g-3g-h-4g-mobile-internet-signal-bar
I find when I'm on the 'E' service (217kbs) I do not have a strong enough connection to get pokestops but I can catch pokemon, but its buggy. I would think anything less would be almost impossible to play on.
Once I move up to 3G (385kbs) and above, including H+ I have no issues.
I have played a lot since release, almost constantly and have reset and reinstalled a few times... So in conclusion you should be fine.

Comment: Really? If I have a weak 4g signal, it becomes borderline unplayable for me. I've never been able to catch anything or spin stops on a 3g signal. Maybe because it's so weak?

Comment: It can also depends on where you are and who your provider is because theoretically is expected to support a speed of around 100Mbps for users in motion and around 1Gbps for stationary users. The most recent report on LTE speeds on networks worldwide shows that the Vodafone ES network in Spain was the fastest offering speeds of around 25.2Mbps on average. Spain was the country with the best speeds providing an average of 18Mbps.
You can view the report here https://opensignal.com/reports/2015/02/state-of-lte-q1-2015/

Comment: Also what provider are you thinking of switching two and where are you? ( like what country/ city)

Comment: I'm not OP, was just surprised by your answer. I'm currently with Verizon in the USA if that's of interest to anyone, though.